# How can i run a a unit Test in Apache Camel

Tags: unit-testing, junit, apache-camel, tdd

I want to know the comand line in maven to run unit tests for Apache Camel.
Any help please?
Regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal maven test commands like mvn clean test

if you have to run specific unit test then you have to use

mvn -Dtest=**TestClass**#**testMethod** test

where TestClass is junit test class and testMethod is actual method to run .

More about camel testing can be accessed here..

http://camel.apache.org/spring-testing.html